# How to get the average of a column data where another column contains a value in a specific range

Tags: excel

Lets say I have two columns in a sheet "Data".

- Column A is the Animal
- Column B is the Time value hh:mm:ss

I would like to get the average Time value of all Animals in Column A that are in a specific range of another sheet "Animals" range J50:J90. In this example the average should not include Tree as "Tree" is not in the specific range (J50:J90).

The sheet for the below is called "Data"

```
   |    A     |    B     |
___|__________|__________|
1  |   Animal |   Time   |
___|__________|__________|
2  |   dog    | 00:30:10 |
___|__________|__________|
3  |   cat    | 02:11:00 |
___|__________|__________|
4  |   tree   | 00:45:00 |
___|__________|__________|
```

The sheet containing the range is "Animals", Column J, rows 50 to 90

```
   |    J     |
___|__________|
50 |   dog    | 
___|__________|
51 |   cat    |
___|__________|
52 |   bird   |
___|__________|
53 |   bat    | 
___|__________|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with **array** formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(COUNTIF($H$1:$H$4;$A$2:$A$4)>0;$B$2:$B$4))
```

[image]

> **NOTE**: Because it's an array formula, it must be entered pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or it won't work!

**UPDATE:**: The formula will work of you do `=AVERAGE(IF(COUNTIF($H$1:$H$4;A:A)>0;B:B))` but it may overload file and create performance issues.

In that case, I would use a helper column, indeed:

[image]

Formula in helper column is (and drag down)

`=COUNTIF($H$1:$H$4;A2)`

To get average, then use AVERAGEIF:

```
=AVERAGEIF(C:C;1;B:B)
```

This will not overcharge your calculation as heavy as an array formula would do if you want to use full column

Comment: I should have mentioned. I dont want to have to specify the data column row numbers A2:A4 & B2:B4 as the number of rows is unknown. Will this formula still work if I replace A2:A4 to A:A and B2:B4 to B:B ?

Comment: Yes it will but it will heavily overcharge calculation time. Using array formulas with full columns make overcharge sheet. Consider in that case using a helper column and then using that helper column as criteria to get your average. I'll post an example.

Comment: should this formula work with sheet referencing? i get a popup error which wont accept the formula

=AVERAGE(IF(COUNTIF(animals!$J50:$J90;data!$A:$A)>0;data!$B:$B))

Comment: i cant seem to get excel to take the formula even with all the data in the same sheet like you demonstrated. When I input the formula and press ctrl+shift+enter i get a popup "there's a problem with this formula. I added the screenshot to the post

Comment: i think i fixed it by replacing the semi column `;` character in the formula to a comma `,`

Comment: Sorry for answering late, but yes, replacing `;` with `,` should work. And also about sheet referencing. The `,` depends on language settings.